# How To read Column values in excel file in java.?

Tags: apache-poi

I am having the Excel Sheet

```
UserName    Password

Rahul       test123$


Manish      Password

test        newpwd
```

So when i pass value "test" i should get the "newpwd" as output.

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you may use "jxl" library of java .

try this:

```
package com.quicklyjava;
```

import jxl.*;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaExcelRead {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        //Create a workbook object from the file at specified location.
        //Change the path of the file as per the location on your computer.
        Workbook wrk1 =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/test.xls"));

        //Obtain the reference to the first sheet in the workbook
        Sheet sheet1 = wrk1.getSheet(0);

        //Obtain reference to the Cell using getCell(int col, int row) method of sheet
        Cell colArow1 = sheet1.getCell(0, 0);
        Cell colBrow1 = sheet1.getCell(1, 0);
        Cell colArow2 = sheet1.getCell(0, 1);

        //Read the contents of the Cell using getContents() method, which will return
        //it as a String
        String str_colArow1 = colArow1.getContents();
        String str_colBrow1 = colBrow1.getContents();
        String str_colArow2 = colArow2.getContents();

        //Display the cell contents
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col A Row 1: \""+str_colArow1 + "\"");
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col B Row 1: \""+str_colBrow1 + "\"");
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col A <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD12">Row 2</span>: \""+str_colArow2 + "\"");


    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your help but i wanted to get particular value from that column when i pass relevant value from the another column values from same row... 
like when i pass the "Rahul" from the main method then it should give me "test123$" as output

Comment: for this you take an itration from 0th row to onward , if ( sheet1.getCell(i, j).getContents() == "Rahul") .if condition true  then increment the value of j and getContents of those cell.

Comment: Can you please share me the Code

Comment: Thanks Rohit It is working now. Thank you so much for you help